# .htaccess rewrite to nginx config

Tags: url, redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Need help in converting .htaccess rewrite rules to nginx config. The rules are from the metro shrink url shortner script.

```
RewriteEngine On 
#RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^developer.html$            developer.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^multishrink.html$          multishrink.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^stats.html$                public-stats.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^feed.rss                   feed.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.qrcode$           qrcode.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api.php$                   API/simple.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^API/write/(get|post)$      API/write.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^API/read/(get|post)$       API/read.php?method=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/stats$             stats.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/unlock$            unlock.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

# If path is not a directory or file then apply RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d        
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,60})$      go.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should do the trick:

```
location = /developer.html { rewrite ^ developer.php last; }
location = /multishrink.html { rewrite ^ multishrink.php last; }
location = /stats.html { rewrite ^ stats.php last; }

location ~ ^feed.rss { rewrite ^ feed.php last; }
location ~ ^([^/]+)\.qrcode$ { rewrite ^([^/]+)\.qrcode$ qrcode.php?id=$1 last; }

location = /api.php { rewrite ^ API/simple.php; }
location ~ ^API/(write|read)/(get|post)$ { 
  rewrite ^API/(write|read)/(get|post)$ API/$1.php?method=$2 last;     
} 

location ~ ^([^/]+)/stats$ { rewrite ^([^/]+)/stats$ stats.php?id=$id last;}

location ~ ^([^/]+)/unlock$ {
  set $id $1;
  rewrite ^ unlock.php?id=$id last;  
}

location ~ "^([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,60})$" {
  try_files $uri $uri/ go.php?id=$1;
}
```

Note: that you can either re-use the captures from the location regex by saving them first (as in the unlock location), or you can repeat the regex (the need to save comes from the fact that the rewrite directive resets the capture variables). Use whichever style you prefer.

Note: nginx appends query arguments by default so qsa flag from apache is essentially the default, from http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite:

```
 If a replacement string includes the new request arguments, the previous request 
 arguments are appended after them. If this is undesired, putting a question mark
 at the end of a replacement string avoids having them appended
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I got two errors 1) invalid parameter "=404"            2) invalid number of argument in "set" directive

Comment: another error [emerg] pcre_compile() failed missing ) in "^([0-9a-zA-Z-]"

Comment: the pcre_compile was because the regex involved curly braces which are also used for delineating blocks, so the regex has to be quoted. fixed in my answer

Comment: the invalid parameter =404 is fixed, as is the set directive (the =404 was caused by leaving part of a try_files i had before deciding doing it with rewrite was clearer, the set one I forgot to add the 2nd paremeter telling it wat to set $id to ), both fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location = /developer.html { 
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /developer.php break; 
} 

location = /multishrink.html { 
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /multishrink.php break; 
} 

location = /stats.html { 
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /public-stats.php break; 
} 

location /feed { 
   rewrite ^/feed.rss /feed.php break; 
} 

location / { 
   rewrite ^/([^/]+)\.qrcode$ /qrcode.php?id=$1 break; 
   rewrite ^/([^/]+)/stats$ /stats.php?id=$1 break; 
   rewrite ^/([^/]+)/unlock$ /unlock.php?id=$1 break; 
   if (!-e $request_filename){ 
      rewrite "^/([0-9a-zA-Z-]{1,60})$" /go.php?id=$1 break; 
   } 
} 

location = /api.php { 
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /API/simple.php break; 
} 

location /API { 
   rewrite ^/API/write/(get|post)$ /API/write.php?method=$1 break; 
   rewrite ^/API/read/(get|post)$ /API/read.php?method=$1 break; 
}
```

Comment: thanks got it working after I change all the "break" into "last"